# how to change actionbar tab height with code

Tags: android

i use Swipe View with Tab layout, i need to change tabs height, i read so many answer about this but those didn`t work for me. my codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());





        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded));
        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_brown_dark)));
        //actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundedd));





        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

also i need to change the indicator color ( the blue color ) on this photo :

[enter link description here](http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/1174014272039165621_Screenshot_%DB%B2%DB%B0%DB%B1%DB%B5-%DB%B0%DB%B3-%DB%B2%DB%B4-%DB%B1%DB%B7-%DB%B5%DB%B2-%DB%B1%DB%B2.png)

can you help me pls?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you have to manipulate the action bar tabs, i would just create my own tabs view instead of using the action bar tabs bar. Its implementation is tight and not highly customizable. (i.e. you cannot overlay the tabs bar without hidding them). 
For this purpose,  use as your own tabs bar a radio group view and customize each radio button as a rectangle instead of a circle. If you need it to be scrollable place your radio group inside of a horizontal scroll view and then listen for clicks events to scroll the radio buton (selected tab) to the middle. It requires some maths but there are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: thanks , it is good point, but how can i change activity layout when user clicked on radio buttons?

Comment: Create a viewpager custom adapter. You can create a method called addtab(radiobutton, fragment, bundle). Inside this fragment, when the user selects a radiobutton, you scroll to that page and when the user scrolls to a page you set the radio button as selected.